# can I get popup window layout params?

Tags: java, android, popup, android-linearlayout

I have a popup window

I want to change it's position at runtime after it's already shown.

How can I get its "LayoutParams" to set it to a new position?

the following methods didn't give accurate result for me:

setDropDown

update

setAtPosition (second time..)

Comment: Cannot you just find the view?

Comment: and then how to position it? I want to use getLayoutParams